# Using Mass distribution principle to provide lower bound for the Hausdorff dimension of Cantor set

Tags: probability, analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

given the (ternary) Cantor set $\mathcal{C}$ it is well known that its Hausdorff dimension is given by $\dim_\mathcal{H}(\mathcal{C})=ln(2)/ln(3)$, which I am going to denote by $\alpha$. I am especially interested in the computation of the following lower bound:
$$
\mathcal{H}^{\alpha}(\mathcal{C}) \geq 1/2.
$$
I can provide a proof applying basic properties and the definition, however I am especially interested in providing a proof using the mass distribution principle (similiar to the energy method presented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3562325/hausdorff-dimension-and-mass-distribution)). Let us (briefly) recall the Mass distribution principle first.

**Mass Distribution Principle**: Let $E$ be a set in a metric space $(X,d)$ that supports a finite Borel measure $\mu$ such that for all $x \in E$ and $r>0$ one has
$$
\mu(B(x,r)) \leq C r^{s}
$$
Then one has
$$
\mathcal{H}^{s}(E) \geq \mu(E)/C > 0,
$$
and hence one has $\dim_{\mathcal{H}} \geq s$.

**Setup-Cantor Set**:

I want to provide a "probabilistic" setting for this task where one uses the representation of the Cantor set in terms of $3$-adic expansion, for this I believe the following points are valid:

1. Consider the Cantor set $\mathcal{C} = \{ \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{2 a_n}{3^n} : a_n \in \{0,2\}\}$, where each number is presented in terms of its $3$-adic expansion.
2. Using the measure descripted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1653250/is-there-a-probability-measure-on-the-cantor-set) and denote this by $\mu$, that is constructed as follows: Take $\Omega = \{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$, the sigma Algebra$\mathcal{A}$ that is generated by the following cylinder sets
   $$
   \{\omega \in \Omega : \forall S \subseteq \mathbb N \text{ finite} : a_n \in \{0,2\}\}.
   $$
   And finally the measure $\mu = \prod_{n \in \mathbb N} \mu_n$ where for each $n$ one has $\mu_n(\omega_n = 1) = 1/2$ and then extend this to all Borel sets $B \subset \mathcal{A}$ by Kolmogorov extension theorem. This is the "natural" measure that we want to use for the Mass distribution principle.
3. We need to estimate $\mu(B(x,r))$ for arbitary $r>0$ and $x \in \mathcal{C}$, however one can show that a calculation on $3$-adic grids on generation $n$ sufficies where $I_n(x) = [\frac{k-1}{3^n},\frac{k}{3^n})$ contains $x$. Thus we only need to estimate on balls of radius $B(x,3^{-n})$ for some $n$ (In case the ball has radius bigger than 1/3 one can reduce it to the 1/3 case by using similiarity of the left and right side of the cantor set).

We are now ready to give the proof. Take arbitary $x \in \mathcal{C}$, by the last point it sufficies to proof that
$$
\mu(B(x,3^{-n})) \leq C 3^{-\alpha n} = C 2^{-n}.
$$
But this is easy now, since $B(x,3^{-n})$ contains all the points $y \in \mathcal{C}$ such that there $3$-adic expansion agrees on the first $n$ digits and then starts to differ. Using $(2)$ there are exactly $\frac{1}{2^{-n}}$ choices and hence the above inequality holds. Applying the mass distribution principle yields
$$
\dim_{\mathcal{H}}(\mathcal{C}) \geq \alpha.
$$

**Question**: Is this correct? Is there a cleaner way to write this in terms of $(3)$, i.e. a direct argument why one can only take balls of radius $r=3^{-n}$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would remove those $\times$ in expressions like $C\times 3^{-\alpha n}$. Just write $C3^{-\alpha n}$. That $\times$ is redundant and it only adds confusion.

Comment: Allright, I made the changes accordingly, do you find something else unclear?

Comment: There still is a $\times$ in the mass principle :-)

Comment: Ah yes sorry, it is finally fixed now :) What do you think of the proof.